# Keycloak initial user in a realm

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I am using keycloak 11.0.2 running on Kubernetes and it is deployed through helm chart. In my scenario the Admin Console will not be accessible and all user management will be done through an external SPA page that interacts with Keycloak through the administration api.

I figure out how to preload a realm in keycloack from the helmchart. The realm created does contain at startup a set of roles and one user with administrativie privileges.

When a user connect to this SPA, the login page from keycloack is shown and the user has to login, then if its role is the right one he can add new users to our realm.

The problem is that, even if the initial user is set with the required action "Change Password at first login", when he does the first login the systems asks anyway for the current password, that it's not set.

There is a way to make this user like the admin of keycloack, where at the first tempative the user has to type in the password to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Keycloak allows you to do that through the use of the [User Registration](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_user-registration) feature. To enable this feature go to:

- your `realm settings` page;
- click on the `login` tab
- switch `User registration` to `ON`

[image: User registration feature]